# Menu button in gtk3 not working

Tags: c, menu, gtk3

I'm using gtk3 in Anjuta with C, with the following cut-out version of my code:

```
u.wMenuButton = gtk_menu_button_new();
u.weaponMenu = gtk_menu_new();
u.weaponCI = gtk_menu_item_new();
u.weapon = gtk_button_new_with_label("Punch");

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(u.horizontal), u.wMenuButton, TRUE, TRUE, 1);
gtk_menu_button_set_popup (GTK_MENU_BUTTON(u.wMenuButton), u.weaponMenu);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(u.weaponCI), u.weapon);
gtk_menu_attach(GTK_MENU(u.weaponMenu), u.weaponCI, 0, 1, 0, 1);
```

The only difference in my real code is that I used an array of "weaponCI" and "weapon" and formatted each one identical to the above. I've tried NOT using an array, but it didn't work. I've tried different menu_attach column and row combinations, and nothing worked. I've tried using menubars as indicated in tutorials, and it didn't make a difference. I've reviewed the documentation and some tutorials, and I can't figure out what I have wrong.

I've almost completely sure that my headers and everything is fine, and nothing but the menu is working wrong.

However, the menu still pops up as a tiny flat rectangle with nothing in it at the corner of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, did you try to call `gtk_widget_show_all` on it ?

Comment: Thanks so much! I assumed that calling gtk_widget_show_all on the window would show the menu too... Stupid me.

Comment: `gtk_widget_show_all` propagates to the children, so you're right there. But if you haven't added the widget to your window before calling `gtk_widget_show_all` on the window, then your widget won't automatically have the `visible` property set if you add it afterwards. The basic rule is: create you widget tree by adding all the widgets in the right containers, *then* call `gtk_widget_show_all` on the toplevel widget (your GtkWindow, in this case).